# How to solve $y’’(t)=y(t)+t$

Tags: derivatives

How to solve the ODE
$$
y’’(t)=y(t)+t,
$$
with initial conditions $y(0)=0$ and $y’(0)=0$.

I’ve found $y=-t$ and $y=e^t-t$, but both aren’t valid solutions because of the two initial conditions.

Comment: The homogeneous solution should be $c_1e^t+c_2e^{-t}$

Comment: You can use a Green-function. That involves boundaryvalues within derivatives

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First solve the homogeneous part $y''-y=0$., put $y=e^{mt}$, you get $m=\pm 1$, so
$y=A e^t + B e^{-t}$. Next let $y=p t +q$ in $y''-y=t \implies 0-p t -q =t \implies p=-1, q=0$. Thius the complrtre solution is $$y= A e^{t} +B e^{-t}-t.$$

Answer (score 0):

Using Duhamel’s principle.

Firstly, we consider u solves the problem

$$\left\{\begin{array}{rl} u’’-u =0&t>s;\\u=0,u’=s&t=s.
\end{array}\right.$$
Then we get
$$u(t;s)=\frac{s}{2}e^{t-s}-\frac{s}{2}e^{-(t-s)}.$$
Hence by duhamel’s principle we know
\begin{align}
y(t)&=\int_0^t u(t;s)\,ds\\
&=\int_0^t \frac{s}{2}e^{t-s}-\frac{s}{2}e^{-(t-s)}\,ds\\
&=\frac{1}{2}e^t-\frac{1}{2}e^{-t}-t.
\end{align}
That is the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using power series expansion and a simple linear least-squares:

Set up polynomial basis (truncated power series), add some small regularization, for example [Tihkhonov regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization), ($\epsilon = \lambda$):

$$\bf M = D^2 - I$$

$$\min_{\bf v}\left\{\|{\bf Mv-d}\|_2^2 + \epsilon \|{\bf v}\|_2^2\right\}$$

Initial conditions directly translate to $${\bf v}_1 = {\bf v}_2=0$$ which we can enforce with adding cost function:
$$ + \|{\bf Cv}\|_2^2$$

$\bf C$ diagonal matrix two upper left elements 1 and rest 0.

We can solve in some software for example Matlab:

$$\begin{bmatrix}   0.166666666666666  &0.166666666666667\\
   0.008333333333333&   0.008333333333333\\
   0.000198412698411&   0.000198412698413\\
   0.000002755731878&   0.000002755731922\\
   0.000000025050038&   0.000000025052108\end{bmatrix}$$

left is solved non-zero coefficients.

Right is [Taylor expansion](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor%20expand%20exp%28x%29%2F2-exp%28-x%29%2F2-x%20to%209%20degree) of solution around $t=0$ according to wolfram alpha:

$$y(t) = \frac{1}{2}\left(e^{t}-e^{-t}\right) - t$$